# Spring boot WebServiceTemplate SoapActionCallback - set keystore and TLS

Tags: java, soap-client

I've this code in java 8

```
String u = "https://test.com.asmx?WSDL";
String pwd = "aaaa";
String pathP12 = "1234.p12";
            
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathP12);
ks.load(fis, pwd.toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, pwd.toCharArray());            
            
URL url = new URL(u);
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
System.out.println("After url connection");
```

How can i set TLSv1 and keystore in a `SoapActionCallback` in Spring Boot

```
ProvaResponse response = (ProvaResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
                request,
                new SoapActionCallback("http://www.test.com/Prova")
            );
```

Comment: You don't. You need to configure your template with that.

Comment: With the above code is it all ok. With the above i get error 403. So i think is not using the correct certificate

Comment: Your code above either works or it doesn't. Regardless those to code blocks have nothing to do with each other. You simply haven't configured the proper connection factories for the WebServiceTemplate and as such it won't use what you have configured. But as stated that is configuration and you don't do that with a callback.

Comment: How can i configure WebServiceTemplate?